# Cant declare a function for an object in JavaScript

Tags: javascript, methods, declaration

I am attempting to declare an object function but cant seem to get it to work. I keep getting an Uncaught syntax error: Unexpected token. This happens on the line of the constructor methodn in which try to define my method. Code below.

```
function Car(make, model, year, owner) {
  this.make = make;
  this.model = model;
  this.year = year;
  this.owner = owner; 
  this.setOwner: function (newOwner){
            this.owner = newOwner;
    }
}


var AndrewsCar = new Car("Ford","Focus", 1999, "Andrew");
AndrewsCar.setOwner("Bobbie");
document.writeln(AndrewsCar.owner);
```

What about this. Can I also declare a function like this?

```
 Car.setOwner = function (newOwner){
            this.owner = newOwner;
}
```

I've been trying and when I try to call it I get a TypeDef Error.

Comment: You should define `Car.setOwner` outside of `Car` constructor: `function Car(make, model, year, owner) {
  this.make = make;
  this.model = model;
  this.year = year;
  this.owner = owner;
}; Car.setOwner = function (newOwner){
            this.owner = newOwner;
} `

Comment: I get Object# <Car> has no method 'setOwner'.

Comment: Actually I understand your problem, you should invoke `c = new Car(...)` because `Car` is constructor, so this example actually works: `function Car(make, model, year, owner) {
  this.make = make;
  this.model = model;
  this.year = year;
  this.owner = owner; 
  this.setOwner = function (newOwner){
            this.owner = newOwner;
    }
}
undefined
c = new Car('foo', 'bar', 1954, 'asdsa')
Car {make: "foo", model: "bar", year: 1954, owner: "asdsa", setOwner: function}
c.setOwner('Lala')
undefined
c.owner
"Lala"`

Answer (score 1):

```
  this.setOwner = function (newOwner){
//              ^
```

You had a `:`. To assign properties, you need to use the `=` operator. `:` is used in object literals.

Answer (score 0):

```
this.setOwner: function (newOwner){
            this.owner = newOwner;
    }
```

should be:

```
this.setOwner = function (newOwner){
            this.owner = newOwner;
    }
```

The `:` is needed when you declare methods of an object.

Comment: I thought I was trying to declare a method of an object? Except my incorrect syntax what am I misconceiving?

Comment: I'm sorry, I mean when you do it like this way: `a = { b: function() { ... } }`